# How to merge these queries that insert columns to table

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have selected these data using cursor. And like this, I can insert that data each one. I need to merge that queries in only one insert command.

```
CURSOR moc_local_call_records
      IS
      SELECT RECIPIENT, COUNT(*) N_CNT
      FROM (SELECT RECIPIENT,
                   SERVICE_TYPE,
                   MPS_SWTCH_CD,
                   MPS_FTR_CD1
            FROM ABA_RM_INB_USAGE
            WHERE SERVICE_TYPE = 100
               OR SERVICE_TYPE = 0
              AND MPS_SWTCH_CD = 'T11'
              AND MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1033)
      GROUP BY RECIPIENT;

CURSOR moc_local_home_records
      IS
      SELECT RECIPIENT, COUNT(*) N_CNT
      FROM (SELECT RECIPIENT,
                   SERVICE_TYPE,
                   MPS_FTR_CD1
            FROM ABA_RM_INB_USAGE
            WHERE SERVICE_TYPE = 100
               OR SERVICE_TYPE = 0
              AND MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1031)
      GROUP BY RECIPIENT;
```

And like this i can insert that data each one.

```
FOR mocLocalCallRecords IN moc_local_call_records
      LOOP
        IF mocLocalCallRecords.N_CNT > 0 THEN
          INSERT INTO TRAFFIC_PREPROCESS_INB(TADIG, MOC_LOCAL_CALL_RECORDS)
          VALUES (mocLocalCallRecords.RECIPIENT, mocLocalCallRecords.N_CNT);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

FOR mocLocalHomeRecords in moc_local_home_records
      LOOP
        IF mocLocalHomeRecords.N_CNT > 0 THEN
          INSERT INTO TRAFFIC_PREPROCESS_INB(moc_local_home_records)
          VALUES (mocLocalHomeRecords.N_CNT);
        end if;
end loop;
```

I need to merge that queries in only one insert command. Give me some advice, I'm beginner here by the way

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: ORACLE PL/SQL  ----------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Well then **please add** that `oracle` tag to your question!

Answer (score 1):

You can directly insert it like this if you are not performing any transformations in between:

```
INSERT INTO TRAFFIC_PREPROCESS_INB(TADIG, MOC_LOCAL_CALL_RECORDS,MOC_LOCAL_HOME_RECORDS)
SELECT RECIPIENT, COUNT(*) N_CNT, NULL
      FROM (SELECT RECIPIENT,
                   SERVICE_TYPE,
                   MPS_SWTCH_CD,
                   MPS_FTR_CD1
            FROM ABA_RM_INB_USAGE
            WHERE SERVICE_TYPE = 100
               OR SERVICE_TYPE = 0
              AND MPS_SWTCH_CD = 'T11'
              AND MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1033)
      GROUP BY RECIPIENT
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;

UNION ALL 

SELECT NULL, NULL, COUNT(*) N_CNT
  FROM (SELECT RECIPIENT,
               SERVICE_TYPE,
               MPS_FTR_CD1
        FROM ABA_RM_INB_USAGE
        WHERE SERVICE_TYPE = 100
           OR SERVICE_TYPE = 0
          AND MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1031)
  GROUP BY RECIPIENT
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;
```

Comment: And how to insert next one ?

Comment: Same way. Insert into traffic_preprocess_inb select n_cnt from (your query)

Comment: Did this help you..??

Comment: Actually no :( I need to insert filtered data to table column by column that's my problem. Then I can insert that table into another table directly.

Comment: if you need to insert data into two tables, you should have two insert queries. The condition of count > 0 is performed by 'HAVING' clause and so hopefully the updated answer should suffice your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

why you are using cursor for this ? you easily can insert with 1 insert command like that :

```
INSERT INTO TRAFFIC_PREPROCESS_INB(TADIG, MOC_LOCAL_CALL_RECORDS)
select RECIPIENT, N_CNT 
from (
SELECT RECIPIENT, COUNT(*) N_CNT
      FROM (SELECT RECIPIENT,
                   SERVICE_TYPE,
                   MPS_SWTCH_CD,
                   MPS_FTR_CD1
            FROM ABA_RM_INB_USAGE
            WHERE SERVICE_TYPE = 100
               OR SERVICE_TYPE = 0
              AND MPS_SWTCH_CD = 'T11'
              AND MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1033)
      GROUP BY RECIPIENT
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
union all
SELECT NULL as RECIPIENT, COUNT(*) N_CNT
FROM (SELECT RECIPIENT,
             SERVICE_TYPE,
             MPS_FTR_CD1
      FROM ABA_RM_INB_USAGE
      WHERE SERVICE_TYPE = 100
           OR SERVICE_TYPE = 0
          AND MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1031)
 GROUP BY RECIPIENT
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
  )X
```

i hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Both your queries are very similar with little difference of predicates in where clause. Since you are grouping by RECIPIENT and want a Count(*), they could both be merged into a much simpler query, like so

```
SELECT RECIPIENT, COUNT(*) N_CNT       
FROM ABA_RM_INB_USAGE
WHERE SERVICE_TYPE IN (100, 0)    
  AND ((MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1033 AND MPS_SWTCH_CD = 'T11')      
        OR MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1031)  
GROUP BY RECIPIENT
```

Further, you want to insert those records from this SELECT for which COUNT(*) is greater than zero in another table. This could be achieved with a single INSERT statement without use of cursor hence with better performance, like so

```
INSERT INTO TRAFFIC_PREPROCESS_INB
(TADIG, MOC_LOCAL_CALL_RECORDS)
SELECT RECIPIENT, COUNT(*) N_CNT       
FROM ABA_RM_INB_USAGE
WHERE SERVICE_TYPE IN (100, 0)    
  AND ((MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1033 AND MPS_SWTCH_CD = 'T11')      
        OR MPS_FTR_CD1 = 1031)  
GROUP BY RECIPIENT
HAVING N_CNT > 0
```